# How to get paymentMethodNonce in Braintree API?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.4, braintree-sandbox

I'm working in laravel 5.4
My transactions are successfull when I try a 'fake_nonce' type of string provided by the braintree docs. But when I tried to get the paymentMethodNonce it always gives me error like nonce not found. And sometimes http error!!! If I try to configure it by myself!
Take a look at my controller function below

```
public function addOrder(Request $request){
  $customer = Braintree_Customer::create([
    'firstName' => $request->guest_name,
    'email' => $request->guest_email,
    'phone' => $request->guest_phone
  ]);
  $customer->success;
  $customer->customer->id;
  $find = Braintree_Customer::find($customer->customer->id);
  $nonceFromTheClient = Braintree_PaymentMethodNonce::find($find);
  $result = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => $request->subtotal,
    'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonceFromTheClient,
    'options' => [
      'submitForSettlement' => True
    ]
  ]);
  if ($result->success) {
      $settledTransaction = $result->transaction;
  } else {
      print_r($result->errors);
  }
  Cart::destroy();
  return view('guest/track', compact('result'));
}
```

Comment: Please help me!!!

Answer (score 0):

`$nonceFromTheClient = Braintree_PaymentMethodNonce::find($find);`

Your using the wrong nonce, this nonce must come from the DropIn ui and not be generated on your code.

Please check the onPaymentMethodReceived() method provided in the JS SDK.

[Please check this reference](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/best-practices#custom-ui)